# python reading strings

Tags: python, string

Can anyone help me with the following query
what is the pythonic way to cleanse the following strings:

Lets say I have the word

```
"abcd
```

or

```
'blahblah
```

then the words actually are

```
abcd, blahblah
```

I can think of a basic way.. but actually I am reading a huge text file..
and explicitly writing a code to read char by char seems like overkill and definitely not pythonic.. I am sure there is a pythonic way to do this..:)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip unwanted characters from the beginning and end of a string using the `str.strip()` method.

```
>>> '"abcd'.strip( '"\'' )
'abcd'
>>> '\'blahblah'.strip( '"\'' )
'blahblah'
>>> print( '"abcd'.strip( '"\'' ) )
abcd
>>> print( '\'blahblah'.strip( '"\'' ) )
blahblah
```

Comment: and how do you strip down the single quotes in the start and the end..? Shouldnt the out put be like abcd and not 'abcd'

Comment: No, it’s just in quotes because the return value itself is a string. If you print the value itself, you’ll see that there are no more quotes in the string. Changed my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want just the alphabetical characters from each word.

```
import re
_regex = r'\W+' #word characters only    

#read in input
#split input on ' ' (space), to get words

for word in list_of_words:
    word = re.sub(_regex, '', word)
```